# website - Realtime Application

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, socket.io, realtime-api

I would like to create an website with **much realtime traffic**. So my question is:

**Is node.js and socket.io the right way?**

(I'm ready to learn and have a good knowledge at PHP,JQUERY,JS,CSS,MYSQL and VB.NET)

Comment: node.js would be used on the backend side for the api. On the frontend side  you can use something like meteor js which was developed with realtime data in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Node is a great language and if you like Javascript already, I believe it can be a great language to learn.  The simplest way to get a simple web server up and running is Express (http://expressjs.com/).  With express you can start a server and serve static content (your html pages).

Here is a quick guide to get started in Node.js

1. Install Node
2. Create a directory from which to work in
3. Run `npm init`
4. Answer the questions in the prompts
5. Install Express `npm install --save express`
6. Create a file called app.js
7. Copy the following code into the file:

```js
    'use strict';
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const HTTP_PORT = 3000;
    
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    
    app.listen(HTTP_PORT);
    console.log('Listening on port: ' + HTTP_PORT + ' -- Open http://localhost:' + HTTP_PORT);
```

8. Make a folder named 'public'
9. Create a new HTML file called index.html
10. Add some content
11. Start your node server with `node app.js`
12. Open a browser to `http://localhost:3000`

Congratulations, you now have a real working node server, that serves static content and can handle ajax requests!

There is a ton of info I could put next, but I recommend checking out the express documentation to find how to handle routing and api requests.

Good luck and happy learning!

If you want a shortcut, I threw together a tiny starter pack of code that does all of the following and includes an API request example.
https://github.com/DuaneGarber/nodeExpressStarter

Simply pull down the code, `npm install`, then start the server `node app.js`, open localhost:3000 in a browser.

Comment: Ok thanks but I would like to create an realtime Application with much Traffic so is nodejs and socketio the right way

Answer (score 0):

If you have good or fair knowledge of javascript then you should go for Meteor.

Meteor

https://www.meteor.com/

Sample tutorial you should start with

http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/